# Datamodel structure change frequently: best way to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, database-migration

I have always used Coredata in my iOS (swift and objectiveC) application.

Now in my new project i have this situation; datamodel change frequently. For example attribute that previously was a String became a Relation or vice versa, String became NSNumber, Relation disappear leaving Entity detached from the other table, etc.

Coredata remains the best solution?
I must write always a migration script to resolve migration problem?

Answer (score 2):

Core Data is best compared to what? On what axis of measure? Ease of managing data model migration? Query speed? Object <-> storage interaction?

You could compare on many axes.

First, an observation, migrating data on devices in the field is a problem. Any database is going to take some time to migrate. Time where the app is unresponsive. Users can kill the app during migration thinking it is dead. Hence, take care how often you change your schema. You will lose customers for every unresponsive app at startup. Your colleagues may not understand how fickle customers may be. Users probably don't care enough about your app to suffer any kind of lengthy migration.

In my experience, Core Data handles migration better than most environments. Other environments that use SQLite are unlikely to be more performant. Use a different database? Then you are rewriting every object in your app? WoW! You have more than a migration problem then.

From your question, it sounds like you are undergoing schema churn. That is not a good sign about your development process. I would address that churn before I would consider changing databases.

When you have an option, always use lightweight migration. Think very carefully before you require a mapping model for a hard migration. Lightweight migration tends to be quite efficient in the field. That is a very import characteristic to maintain. Hard migrations are pretty radical mutations of your schema. I work very hard to avoid lengthy migrations.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective **Core Data** is the best solution even in your case you would need to do hard migration.

1. (Hard) migration as not simple changes like changing entity type
   or removing attribute from the entity and others. For this type
   migration you need to write additional scrip what is called
   [migration process](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMigrationProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH6-SW1).
2. [Lightweight migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1) as simple
   changes to your model such as adding a new attribute to an entity and Core Data performs automatic data migration.

It is only my perspective. Lets see what other persons will post here.

[Core Data and Swift: Migration](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-migrations--cms-25084)